# Arduino Mega ADK with USB HUB

Tags: arduino, adk

is it possible to see data of android device when is it in accessory mode??

```
in my opinion what we need 
1. USB hub
2. android phone(which work with accessory mode)
3. Arduino Mega ADk
4. USB cables first for android device and second for USB hub to PC

Connection
1.connect hub with Arduino ADK (where we have connect android device)
2.connect android device with hub(Via usb cable)
3.connect hub with PC(via usb cable)
```

all things i did but my PC is not detected Android device

any kind of suggestion will be appreciated
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Your Android device will not be detected when it is connected to a Mega ADK board. The reason is that both PC and Mega ADK will act as USB Host and so only one can be connected at a time.

If you want to debug and want to see the output of logcat, then you can use ADB Wireless app.

Comment: i got your point
if my connection is 
1.connect USB hub to android device
2.connect hub with ADK and PC as well
this time android device is working as a client but in this method android device did not go into accessory mode....

My main query is if my android device in accessory mode so how could i see the data in logcat

Comment: As I said in my answer, if your Android device is in Accessary mode, then it can't connect to PC. So you can't use the ADB to view logcat messages in PC. The other option is to use ADB Wireless app, which connects to your PC through WIFI and prints the logcat messages.